# I do not understand exactly those RAM speeds

Tags: memory, cpu, speed

So, I was never in situation like this before, I always picked every part so it would fit the performances of Motherboard, CPU and RAM...

But this time, every cent is counting... So... Ryzen 5 2600, and on their page, says "System Memory: 2933 MHz, DDR4, 2 slots. And this motherboard that I found, supports 2133/2400/2666/2933/3200 (So no problem with that so far), but my RAM is 8 GB 2666 MHz. Will this work? I looked it up on Part Picker website, it does not show any issues, but I don't trust it as much.

Can anybody with some real experience say if this will work? (Some explanation would be nice too)

Thanks in advance

Comment: 2 slots are not much, but because the speeds do match, it should work.

Comment: In theory it should match, but there is never any guarantee. Buy the RAM from a supplier that accepts returns.

Answer (score 2):

It will work: The Ryzen 5 2600 can use DDR4 **up to** 2933 MHz, and the Mainboard **between** 2133 **and** 3200. So your 2666 MHz RAM will run fine (although with less speed than the memory controller can handle).